# c++ 2 overloads have similar conversions depending on whether the operator is a member function or a global one

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ambiguous

Consider a simple vector class realization:

```
#include <algorithm>

class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int _elementsCount)
        : elementsCount(_elementsCount)
        , elements(new float[_elementsCount])
    {}
    ~Vector() {
        delete[] elements;
    }
    Vector(const Vector& rhs) {
        elementsCount = rhs.size();
        elements = new float[elementsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < elementsCount; ++i)
            (*this)[i] = rhs[i];
    }

    float& operator [](int i) {
        return elements[i];
    }
    float operator [](int i) const {
        return const_cast<Vector&>(*this)[i];
    }
    int size() const {
        return elementsCount;
    }
    /*// Dot product
    float operator *(const Vector& v) {
        float res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
            res += (*this)[i] * v[i];
        return res;
    }*/
private:
    int elementsCount;
    float* elements;
};

// Multiplication by a scalar
Vector operator *(const Vector& v, float k) {
    Vector res(v.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        res[i] = v[i] * k;
    return res;
}

// Dot product
float operator *(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2) {
    float res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < std::min(v1.size(), v2.size()); ++i)
        res += v1[i] * v2[i];
    return res;
}

void main()
{
    Vector v(2);
    v * 3; // ambiguous
}
```

This code compiles. But if we uncomment * operator realization in the class and comment its global realization (dot product function), then there will be an error "'Vector::operator *': 2 overloads have similar conversions", because there is an ambiguity: whether to call the multiplication by a scalar or to interpret 3 as an argument to a parametrized constructor and to call the dot product. This makes sense. But I don't get what's the difference of declaring the * operator as a member function or as a global function. I thought they should be the same in the example like above, but it's not the case.

**Added.** The thing I most interested in is not how to avoid the ambiguity, but why there is an ambiguity in one case (when * is declared as a member) and there is no one in the other (when * is declared as a global function).

Comment: Make the constructor `explicit` and the ambiguity goes away.

Comment: @Quimby, yeah, but why there is an ambiguity in one case and not it another? (I added the explicit question to the end of the post.)

Comment: See my response in the comments on my answer.  The operators that you assume are equivalent are in fact not, due to having different _constness_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your constructor `explicit`:

```
explicit Vector(int _elementsCount) { ... }
```

The reason for the ambiguity is that the compiler can't decide whether it should implicitly convert a `int` value to a `Vector` and invoke `Vector::operator*`, or implicitly convert a `int` value to a `float` and use `operator*(const Vector&, float)`.

By using `explicit`, such conversions are forbidden, and you must use `Vector(3)` if you want "3" to be a `Vector`.

As a side-note, you should make the operator `const`, since it does not modify the object.  Making it const will also allow it to be used with a `const Vector`:

```
float operator *(const Vector& v) const { ... }
```

Beware that will still conflict with your other overload:

```
float operator *(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2)
```

There is no reason to have both. Choose either the member function or the global function and remove the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you say why does the ambiguity depends on how the function is declared (member vs global)?

Comment: Your member and global declarations are not equivalent.  See my comment about const-correctness.  As you wrote it, your member overload is equivalent to the global overload `float operator*(Vector&, const Vector&)`.... meaning the value on the left of `*` can be modified by the operator.  If you define your global overload that way, you get the same error.  Under the hood, the compiler has a preference to match on `const` references when using operators.